# does html5's websocket can listen a port by browser?

Tags: html, websocket, p2p

I newbee to html5

I find that html5 support the websocket and i have some problem with it

is there any way to create a connect from one browser to an other browser?

like socket.io's server listten a port on my browser?

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if you managed to listen to a port, this would not be enough, because P2P communication is more complicated than that. It includes NAT traversal which is a complex subject requiring a central server to facilitate communication.

Contrary to what Remy Lebeau says: P2P can include going via a server. This is called T.U.R.N. It has been used for years in early P2P systems.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly browser to browser, it needs to go through a server.

Why not use socket.io?

Comment: thanks for your answer ,because i want to create a p2p app use browser

Comment: you would have to write a custom browser plugin in order to do p2p. You won't be able to do it with HTML5 by itself unless both peers go through a server (in which case it is not p2p anymore).

Comment: .. Unless the html5 peerconnection interface is at some point allowed to transport data other than audio and video.